# Facebook requires v3.0 API

Tags: python, facebook, api

Two days ago facebook asked me to use version of sdk 3.0.
While running script I have this problem:

**(#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v3.0.**

For connecting to the API I use:

> ```
> config_filename = os.path.join(this_dir, 'jsons/config.json')
>  config_file = open(config_filename)
>  config = json.load(config_file)
>  config_file.close()
>  session = FacebookSession(
>  config['access_token'],
>  config['app_id'],
>      config['app_secret'],
> )
> api = FacebookAdsApi(session)
> FacebookAdsApi.set_default_api(api)
> print(FacebookAdsApi.API_VERSION)
> ```

- print returns me **v2.11**

Rinning

```
pip install facebook-ads-api
```

Tells:

**Requirement already satisfied: facebook-ads-api in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (0.3.0)**

Looking at documentation right here:
https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html
Status for version 3.0 is **unreleased**

On my facebook account, I upgraded the app to v3.0(from adManager).

So, I can't understand what am I doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: You are confusing the version of an SDK with an API version …

Comment: As far as I understand SDK includes API... Am I right? That means, that i should update only api?

Comment: In general, an SDK and an API are two totally different things, and the version of one has nothing at all to do with that of the other. (It might be that the SDK needs updating to incorporate new functionality added with newer API versions though - but that would be more about specifics of certain request, endpoints, etc.) Check the configuration/ initialization, the API version to use should be specified somewhere in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
config_file = open('jsons/config.json')
config = json.load(config_file)
config_file.close()

session = FacebookSession(
    config['app_id'],
    config['app_secret'],
    config['access_token'],
)
api = FacebookAdsApi(session)

FacebookAdsApi.init(session.app_id, session.app_secret, session.access_token, api_version='v3.0')
```

Olso on page [click](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/) I updated verions of API for an app